# element is not clickable at point(987, 466)

Tags: java, selenium, testng

```
@FindBy(xpath="//input[@name='MiddleName']")
private WebElement middlename;

WebDriverWait clickableWait = new WebDriverWait(getWebDriver(), 120);
    clickableWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(middlename));

    middlename.click();
    middlename.clear();
    waitPlease(2);
    middlename.sendKeys("Jhon");
```

i am using this code to click a input box but i get an error

```
Element <input type="text" value="as" name="MiddleName"> is not clickable at point (987, 466). Other element would receive the click: <div _ngcontent-c8="" class="modal-body" style="padding: 50px; max-height: 500px; overflow-y: scroll;">...</div>
```

the block element not in my webpage so whya thats error coming..

i am using testNG Framework in my project:-
any help for this ,Thanks in advance

Comment: `Selenium` has support for `name`, why would you use `xpath` with `name attribute` ? Also what is `waitPlease(2)` ? why your `framework` has to wrap `thread.sleep()` ?

Comment: there is an element on top of the one you are trying to click.  The exception tells you what that element is.  (Looks like a modal dialog)  Interact with that element first... (maybe click the "close" button)

Comment: As @pcalkins says read the full exception, there will be something like: `Other element would recieve the click` including identification of the overlaying element.

Comment: Try to take screenshot before clicking the element, 
we need to check whether problem is occurring by 
pop-up or screen size or scrolling or invisiblity. after seeing the screenshot, we can clearly know the fault.